# How to calculate disease prevalence by a variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm totally lost in trying to calculate my disease prevalence based on a variable (in my case Postal Code). I've tried everything but nothing seems to work :(

I know disease prevalence is simple to calculate (total number of diseased divided by total population), but it won't let me sum the cases and sum the population by postal code in order to then divide them.

The column I'm trying to calculate prevalence for is called "Lyme" which is a logistic variable (0=negative, 1=positive). Then the column "FSA" is my postal codes. Please help!

Here is my code:

````
Data.All.df <- data.frame(Data.All) ## Create Data Frame from Data file
Data.All.df.2008 <- subset(Data.All.df, Year=="2008") ##only use 2008
library(dplyr)
Data.All.df.2008 <- Data.All.df.2008 %>% 
                              group_by(FSA) %>% 
                              mutate_each(funs(Cases = ((Lyme=="1")/((Lyme=="0")+(Lyme=="1")))))```


X.1 X Source Patient Accession Customer Year Date Country City Province Postal Name Age Gender Species Breed SNAP Apspp Ehrspp HW Lyme Coinfections dupID FSA
1710    4913    4913    Veterinary Clinic   Bronson Sprartacus796575981360  7.97e+13    79657   2008    2008-01-08  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8N 3T4 Bronson Sprartacus  132 Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8N
1711    4915    4915    Veterinary Clinic   Scotty9233669481432 9.23e+13    92336   2008    2008-01-08  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8R 1A5 Scotty  84  Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8R
1712    4916    4916    Veterinary Clinic   Hershey9233683161435    9.23e+13    92336   2008    2008-01-08  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8R 1A5 Hershey 48  Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8R
1713    4918    4918    Veterinary Clinic   Brandy7965736441362 7.97e+13    79657   2008    2008-01-09  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8N 3T4 Brandy  156 Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8N
1714    4919    4919    Veterinary Clinic   Trish9233699481443  9.23e+13    92336   2008    2008-01-10  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8R 1A5 Trish   132 Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8R
1715    4929    4929    Veterinary Clinic   Lexie8001685020761364   8.00e+13    80016   2008    2008-01-17  Canada  HALIFAX NS  B3L 2C2 Lexie   29  Spayed  Canine  Non-Sporting    4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    B3L
1716    4937    4937    Veterinary Clinic   CUBBIE79700431  7.97e+12    79700   2008    2008-01-21  Canada  DARTMOUTH   NS  B2W 2N3 CUBBIE  118 Spayed  Canine  Non-Sporting    4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    B2W
1717    4945    4945    Veterinary Clinic   Stevie7965765291433 7.97e+13    79657   2008    2008-01-25  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8N 3T4 Stevie  36  Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8N
1718    4947    4947    Veterinary Clinic   Bailey9233644191501 9.23e+13    92336   2008    2008-01-25  Canada  WINDSOR ON  N8R 1A5 Bailey  132 Not Specified   Canine  Not Specified   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    N8R
1719    4948    4948    Veterinary Clinic   ZAK925369448482 9.25e+12    92536   2008    2008-01-25  Canada  HUNTSVILLE  ON  P1H 1B5 ZAK 96  Neutered    Canine  Hound   4Dx 0   0   0   0   0   TRUE    P1H
17
````

Comment: You will need to provide example data in a plain text format from `Data.All.df.2008` to get any help.

Comment: maybe, `Data.all.df %>% filter(Year==2008) %>% group_by(FSA) %>% summarise(prev=mean(Lyme))` ... ?

Comment: @neilfws I think I added my data properly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Reading the data is difficult right now, can you limit it to the key columns as per [mcve]? thanks.

Comment: Holly it's important that we have an easily importable sample dataset. Frequently you can do this by taking a sample of your data and using `dput`, but in your case it would likely make more sense to create some toy data as `Lyme == 1` doesn't appear to occur very often. See my answer below for an example of how to create toy data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following minimal example data:

```r
# Generate data.
set.seed(0934)
Data.All.df.2008 <- data.frame(FSA = sample(c("N8N", "N8R", "B3L", "P1H"), 50, T),
                               Lyme = sample(0:1, 50, T),
                               stringsAsFactors = F)

# First 10 observations.
head(Data.All.df.2008)

#   FSA Lyme
# 1 N8N    1
# 2 P1H    1
# 3 N8N    0
# 4 P1H    0
# 5 N8N    1
# 6 N8N    1
```

Prevalence can be calculated as the number of positive diagnoses divided by the total number of observations, i.e. `sum(Lyme)/n()`. The appropriate function is `summarise`:

```r
library(dplyr)

Data.All.df.2008 %>% 
    group_by(FSA) %>% 
    summarise(Prevalence = sum(Lyme)/n())

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   FSA   Prevalence
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 B3L        0.778
# 2 N8N        0.571
# 3 N8R        0.583
# 4 P1H        0.467
```

Comment: IT WORKED! I'm on cloud 9! Thank you so so much! @gersht

Comment: Great to hear it @HollyArcher! Since my answer solves your problem, would you mind upvoting and also accepting the answer by clicking the check mark to the left? That way other people with an issue simlar to yours know what worked for you.

Comment: I clicked the check mark but It said this when I tried to upvote "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I'll try and up my reputation and do it again! :) @gersht